# Get elements in and out of a tag with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I'm a newbie to Jsoup. I want to get '65' and 'PM10' information from the following html. I have tried to get this "a" tag by doc.select(a[href='http://aqicn.org/city/malaysia/johor/larkinlama/']).

```
<a href='http://aqicn.org/city/malaysia/johor/larkinlama/' class='cityaqi citysync'>
Larkin Lama, Johor<span class='citylistaqival oaqi100'><span class='iaqi100'>
<span class='aqival'>65</span></span></span></a>
<span class='indiPm indiPm10'>PM10</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.select("span.aqival").text();

doc.select("span.indiPm").text();
```

Since you are a newbie you can refer to a tutorial series on jsoup in http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/jsoup/a_jsoup.php. It has examples for the widely used jsoup methods

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired output.

`doc.select(".aqival").text()`

`doc.select(".indiPm").text()`